# serial await requests in a return run in parallel?

Tags: javascript, async-await

Having a discussion with someone and came across this oddity:

```
const wait = async () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));

async function case1() {
  const {a, b} = {a: await wait(), b: await wait()};
  return {a, b};
}

async function case2() {
  return {a: await wait(), b: await wait()};
}

async function case3() {
  const {a, b} = {a: wait(), b: wait()};
  return {a: await a, b: await b};
}

async function case4() {
  const {a, b} = {a: wait(), b: wait()};
  const {c, d} = {c: await a, d: await b};
  return {c, d};
}

function test() {
  const start = new Date();

  case1().then(() => console.log('case1:', +new Date() - start));
  case2().then(() => console.log('case2:', +new Date() - start));
  case3().then(() => console.log('case3:', +new Date() - start));
  case4().then(() => console.log('case4:', +new Date() - start));
}
```

`case1` and `case2` both run in 2 seconds.  `case3` and `case4` run in 1 second.

Is there some weird implicit `Promise.all` or something??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call the function `wait()` without utilizing `await` at `case3` and `case4`. That is the difference.

Comment: they're called in all instances and all return exactly the same thing

Comment: No they are not the same. You call `wait()` without `await` at `case3()` and `case4()` calls at `const {a, b} = {a: wait(), b: wait()};` and `const {a, b} = {a: wait(), b: wait()};`, respectively

Comment: yes, they are.  there's an `await` in all of them, so why does `{await fn(), await fn()}` run them in series and `{await result, await result}` run them in parallel?

Comment: Not sure why you have concluded they are the same? They are not the same. You neglect to use `await` at each `case3()` and `case4()` calls at destructuring assignment, then use `await`  at next line, though the calls have already been made at the previous line.

Answer (score 0):

In case#3 the `wait()` functions are called immediately, so there is only 1 second of timeout (for both of them), while in the other two (case#1 and case#2) the `await` will "do it's job" and wait for the async call to return.

As you can see here, the `console.log(Date())` is being called immediately for both calls.

```js
const wait = async () => new Promise(resolve => console.log(Date()) || setTimeout(resolve, 1000));

async function case3() {
  const {a, b} = {a: wait(), b: wait()};
  return {a: await a, b: await b};
}

function test() {
  const start = new Date();
  case3().then(() => console.log('case3:', +new Date() - start));
}
test();
```

And here it is being synchronized using the `await`:

```js
const wait = async () => new Promise(resolve => console.log(Date()) || setTimeout(resolve, 1000));

async function case1() {
  const {a, b} = {a: await wait(), b: await wait()};
  return {a, b};
}


function test() {
  const start = new Date();

  case1().then(() => console.log('case1:', +new Date() - start));
}
test();
```