# Calling function with a Promise hangs when in a loop

Tags: javascript, promise

When you run the following javascript code, it works fine. But if you remove the setTimeout function call and replace it with a line of code like:

```
resolve(x);
```

the browser will hang.

The browser appears to hang because it is processing the calls to processNode function in an endless while loop. But what isn't clear is why there is any blocking going on at all. processNode returns a Promise. Furthermore, the startNodeProcessing is an async function that is using await on the calls. I thought that by having a Promise and async function with await would prevent any blocking of the thread, but clearly I'm wrong. It appears that the setTimeout just executes its code on a separate thread thus preventing blocking. But if this is the case, why bother with a Promise or async function to start with?

```
function processNode(x) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        console.log("X: " + x + "  " + Date.now());
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(x);
        }, x);
    });
}

async function startNodeProcessing() {
    while(true) {
        var a = processNode(1);
        var b = processNode(1);
        var c = processNode(1);
        var d = processNode(1);
        var a1 = await a;
        var b1 = await b;
        var c1 = await c;
        var d1 = await d;
    }

    return;
}

startNodeProcessing();
```

Comment: Because it's generating more and more requests, which will overload the browser which will reach memory boundaries in a certain time.

Comment: What is purpose of using `while` loop within `startNodeProcessing` function? Note, you call the function which returns a `Promise` before using `await`

Comment: JavaScript is single-threaded. Code in setTimeout, though running asynchronously, can still block the main thread.

Comment: *the code like* would be interesting

Comment: @Frxstrem But the code in the setTimeout does not block the main thread and I really doubt it would no matter how long the work within the setTimeout took to complete.

Comment: @guest271314 It's just for illustration purposes.

Comment: @AndroidDev What are you trying to illustrate? What is expected result?

Comment: @Sandrooco So what you are saying is that if I could set the setTimeout to a timeout value like 1 microsecond (which is not possible), I would see the hanging occur? I doubt that. I have a feeling that the setTimeout is running a quasi parallel thread that has no affect on the main thread. But I have no proof of that because I cannot create a setTimeout less than a millisecond.

Comment: @AndroidDev The code in your specific example dosen't block, but if you for example have an infinite loop inside a setTimeout callback, it *will* freeze your page because it blocks the main thread: `setTimeout(function() { while(true); }, 100)`. That being said, I've tried running your code and it doesn't seem to *block* at all..

Comment: Setting an infinite loop inside a setTimeout callback will block. That is clear. But that is not what I am doing. Also, I corrected my post above. I didn't mean var x = 0;  It should be resolve(x); Still, I'm using the latest version of Chrome and it will block.

Answer (score 1):

Well the following happens:

```
 var a = processNode(1);
//the parser jumps to processNode and creates a promise:
return new Promise(function(resolve)
//the promise is resolved
resolve(x);
//the function returns, we enter the main function again:       
var a1 = await a;
//await internally calls the then function:
a1.then(return to this func)
//as the promise is resolved, the then callback is called immeadiately
//the parser returns to the main function
```

As you can see, the parser never exits the loop, therefore it is blocking as it never halts.

Comment: I corrected my code sample. I actually meant resolve(x) instead of var x = 0;

Answer (score 0):

> Furthermore, the startNodeProcessing is an async function that is
>   using await on the calls.

No, `await` is not used on the calls. The call is made at lines before `await`. See [serial await requests in a return run in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45664223/serial-await-requests-in-a-return-run-in-parallel/45664314#45664314)

---

> It blocks without the setTimeout. Just replace setTimeout with
>   resolve(x) and it will block. I'm trying to understand why.

Because `Promise` constructor `executor` function is called immediately, for example, the `console.log()` within `Promise` constructor at Question is called immediately, irrespective of if or when `resolve` function parameter is called.

```
Promise(resolve => {
   console.log("this is not executed asynchrously"); 
   resolve(1)
})
```

[`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

> Syntax
>
> `new Promise( /* executor */ function(resolve, reject) { ... } );`
>
> Parameters
>
> executor
>
> A function that is passed with the arguments resolve and reject. The
>   executor function is executed immediately by the Promise
>   implementation, passing resolve and reject functions (the executor is
>   called before the Promise constructor even returns the created
>   object).

Comment: Technically that is true but that doesn't matter because your response doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @AndroidDev What is your question? You have not clearly defined what you are trying to achieve? Pointed out one issue with existing code use of `await`, that is you use `await` after the function which returns a `Promise` has already been called, negating the functionality of `await` altogether. First explain the purpose of `while` loop then immediately adjust usage of `await`.

Comment: It blocks without the setTimeout. Just replace setTimeout with resolve(x) and it will block. I'm trying to understand why.

Comment: @AndroidDev Because `Promise` constructor `executor` function is called immediately, for example, the `console.log()` within `Promise` constructor. Essentially `Promise(resolve => resolve())` is not asynchronous, `setTimeout()` is asynchronous.

Comment: @AndroidDev In short, there are several issues with code at Question. Though the answer to your specific Question should be found be reading the documentations of the implementation that you are trying to use.